# How do I restore a tar Android backup directly to my Android device?

Tags: android, linux, adb, tar, restore

Android 11. I made a backup of my Internal Storage using this and run .sh:

```
adb exec-out 'tar --create --exclude=data/media/0/TWRP \
data/media/0 2>/backup-errors.txt | \
gzip' | \
dd of=sdcardbakup-$(date +%Y%m%d).tar.gz && \
adb shell cat /backup-errors.txt
```

But how do I restore that directly to my internal storage after formatting?

sorry I don't know anything about this...

using windows 10